# Typescript interface for object with arbitrary keys?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an object that looks like this

```
{
  "sdfsdkhdfs": 1,
  "jjgtusdf": 2
}
```

where the keys are randomly generated, and there's an unspecified number of them. I want to create a type for this object in Typescript. How should I do this?

Comment: I think that `Record<string, number>` is what you need in this case. it just defines a Record with keys of type `string` and values of type `number`

Answer (score 4):

```js
interface MyObject { [key: string]: number };
```

Answer (score 1):

The best you can do here is `Record<string, number>`.